# In a Hugo Base template how can I know which page is being displayed?

Tags: hugo

I have a Hugo template and as you can see below, header and footer are static and child pages are added to the "main" block. I would like the `<body>` to get a class depending on the page being displayed. Is this possible WITHOUT javascript? I mean, do we by any chance have access to the name of the child page from the base?
Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
    {{ partial "header.html" . }}
    {{ block "main" . }}
    {{ end }}
    {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
    {{ partial "nav.html" . }}
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Page Variables to get page information and then use it to change a class on HTML

[Page Variable](https://gohugo.io/variables/page/)

Comment: Yes that helped. Thanks. In my case I could give `class="{{.Type|lower}}"` to the body and easily differentiate pages.